# Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute

Tags: angular, typescript

I am creating an app that has controls to filter out data using pipes. More specifically the app could sort data in alphabetical order using an ngModel `order`.

I am getting the following error:

```
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute AppComponent.html:15
```

Line 15 is this:

```
<option value="150">150</option>
```

Despite what the error message may say, the error disappears when the line 24 is modified so that change this:

```
<th [(ngModel)]="order" (click)="setOrder('address')">Address</th>
```

into this:

```
<th>Address</th>
```

Full app.component.html code:

```
<div class="container">
  <h1>Automatic Teller Machines</h1>

  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="municipality" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Municipality</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <input class="form-control" type="text" id="Municipality" [(ngModel)]="Municipality" placeholder="Municipality"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group row">
    <label for="results_per_page" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Results per page</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
      <select class="form-control" id="results_per_page" [(ngModel)]="per_page">
        <option value="50">50</option>
        <option value="100">100</option>
        <option value="150">150</option>
      </select>
    </div>
  </div>


  <table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th [(ngModel)]="order" (click)="setOrder('address')">Address</th>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Availability</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let atm of atms | search:municipality | pagination:per_page">
        <td>{{ atm.target_address }}, {{ atm.postalcode }}
          {{ ottoautomaatti.municipality}}</td>
        <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.location}}, {{ ottoautomaatti.location_type}}</td>
        <td>{{ ottoautomaatti.availability }} {{ ottoautomaatti.availability_details }}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</div>
```

Full app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ATMsService } from '../app/atms.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  municipality: string;
  atms: atm[] = [];
  per_page: number = 50;
  order: string = "address";

  constructor(public service: ATMsService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.service.getAll().then((data) => {
      this.atms = data;
    })
  }

  setOrder = (order: string) => {
    this.order = order;
  }

}
```

Comment: Do you want `th` to be a control???

Comment: Yes, I want the user to be able to click on a table header to sort the table data.

Comment: You have already set `order` in your ts file. Why do you need ngModel there?